# Is it possible to add a -G option to ~/.ackrc

Tags: ack

When I do

```
ack -G "^.*$" "foo"
```

I get results... but when I put

```
-G "^.*$"
```

or

```
-G="^.*$"
```

or

```
-G
"^.*$"
```

in my `~/.ackrc/ I get no results... Does anyone know if -G can be used in ackrc?

Comment: Just as a sanity check, you aren't using `--noenv` are you? Do other options work when placed in `~/.ackrc`?

Comment: Yeah, I removed everything from `~/.ackrc` except `-G="^.*$"` and ran `ack "foo"` from the command line. Nothing showed up... but then when I remove the line from `~/.ackrc` I get results for foo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a quoting problem. When executed on the command line:

```
$ ack -G="^.*$"
```

ack actually sees the following command line option (after quote processing by the shell)

```
-G=^.*$
```

without the quotes. Since the `~/.ackrc` file is read without shell quote processing, place the above line *without* quotes into `~/.ackrc`.

**Update**: That was only half of it. It looks like you need to use the following line in `~/.ackrc`:

```
-G^.*$
```

I'm not completely sure why the `=` is not permitted there, but including it makes it part of the pattern, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to make a difference. When I have `-G=^.*$` as the only line in `~/.ackrc` I still get no results...

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with that? Would the `-a` option work for you?

Comment: I'm trying to ignore directories with a little intelligence. I'm trying to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799570/ack-excluding-only-one-directory-but-keeping-all-others-with-the-same-name. I want to `--ignore-dir` `vendor` but not `app/javascripts/vendor`...

Comment: BINGO! You're update fixed it. I basically wanted this: `-G^(?!vendor|log|tmp|doc|coverage|public/app).*$` to have more fine-grained control over the way directories are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You could alias ack to ack -G ?